# search flash/swf files in google best way

Tags: flash

Just wondering if there is a way to search flash files in google just like images can be searched. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while searching 
at end of your search code
add "filetype:swf"

Comment: also U can use advance search
select filetype that u want

Comment: Thanks Sagar, For example if i would like to search heart swf files
it would look like this:

heart filetype:swf

Answer (score 1):

I dont know any specific way to do that. But check this [Google cheat sheet](http://www.google.com/help/cheatsheet.html). You may have to combine some of the commands to fine tune what you're looking for. Another [link](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html) for advanced search.

Comment: +1 For "Another [link](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html) for advanced search". Haven't ever seen these operators before.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to do anything to let Google index your flash files.

how ever if you want to search just flash files on the web just add this to your Google search query

```
filetype:swf
```